# What are Shishya Dharma (duties)?

Tags: dharma, guru, shishya

What are the set of rules laid for a shishya? What are his duties towards guru mandal in particular?
And what are the dos and don'ts for him as a upasaka in general?
What Sadachara must a upasaka follow?

Sorry to include multiple questions under one umbrella title. Since, to me all these 4 questions seem to sing same hymn, so clubbed em together.